# Inline calls to non-inline base class functions (what does that mean exactly)?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading through a C++ book and I'm in a section about reducing the object code generated by templates (**Effective C++ III By Scott Meyers**).  One of the examples it gives is:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix: private SquareMatrixBase<T> {
    public:
        SquareMatrix()
            : SquareMatrixBase<T>(n, 0),
              pData(new T[n*n])
        { this->setDataPtr(pData.get()); }

        ... functions ...

    private:
        boost::scoped_array<T> pData;
};
```

where the base class, SquareMatrixBase has a function called:

```
void invert(std::size_t matrixSize);
```

> "The book moves on to say "Regardless of where the data is stored, the
>   key result from a bloat point of view is that now many -- maybe all --
>   of SquareMatrix's member functions can be simple inline calls to
>   non-inline base class versions that are shared with all other matrices
>   holding the same type of data, regardless of their size."

What does it mean by "inline calls to non-inline base class versions..."?  If its an inline call I would have thought it would have put the whole base class version of any function into the place where inline was used, but this would result in the same code bloat I would have thought.  It says this like it's a benefit against code-bloat though.

If you need more background information let me know, the chapters long though and I tried pretty hard to provide background information but I might have missed something.

## ||EDIT - Additional Information||

The purpose of having Square Matrix and Square matrix base in this passage was:

SquareMatrix was originally a standalone template (not derived). It contained a series of functions which did operations based on the template parameter n's value.  So, there was essentially a copy of every function for every value of n used (or for every pair of n, T used) as a new template with those functions was instantiated for each parameter pair.  SquareMatrixBase was created to move the functions dependent on the size parameter to the base class. Since the base class is only instantiated with a type parameter (and not the size) the functions in the base class can be called by passing in the value for size the derived class passes into the base class constructor.  This means there is only one version of the functions for each typename T passed into the SquareMatrix template regardless of the std::size_t n passed in (as opposed to one version of each function for each combination of {T, n}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that `SquareMatrix::invert()` is inlined, so the function doesn't even appear in the resulting code, and instead the protected base function `SquareMatrixBase::invert(n)` is called directly.

Now since that function is *not* inlined, there is only one single instance of that function (for each type `T`), rather than one copy for each size `n`. This stands in stark contrast to the single-class design, where one `invert()` function would be instantiated *for each value of `n`*.

Comment: Thanks :) "the function doesn't even appear in the resulting code" - so if the body of the base class function isn't replicated, and SqureMatrix::invert doesn't appear in the resulting code, what would appear in the resulting code?  E.g. what would be in the generated code if I called { SquareMatrix<double, 6>().invert(); } in some function outside of the class?

Comment: That would cause a call to `SquareMatrixBase<double>::invert(6)`. So you only need one single copy of `SquareMatrixBase<double>::invert()` around.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  I was having a brain fart :p The contents of invert in the derived class would be a forwarding call to SquareMatrixBase<double>::invert(), so inlining the derived call would reusult in placing "SquareMatrixBase<double>::invert();" wherever the derived's function was called.  Thanks man, don't know why that was confusing me so much, it sounds pretty simple now. Greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

It means that (many of) the functions in `SquareMatrix` class will be simple inline functions; and these inline functions will consist of a non-inline call to the base-class function that implements the functionality. For example, `SquareMatrix` may have an `invert()` member, implemented inline as:

```
void invert() {SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(n);}
```

Calling this should generate exactly the same code as a direct call to `SquareMatrixBase::invert(n)`, but with the convenience that the value of `n` is provided as a compile-time constant by the template, saving both the calling code and the implementation from having to keep track of it as a run-time variable.

Comment: Note that `this->invert(n);` wouldn't work, since it could only call `invert` in the derived class because of hiding. Also, the parent's `invert` call needs the pointer to data as an argument (since it can't use `pData`).

Comment: @jpalacek: good point regarding hiding. We are told that the base class is given a pointer to the data during construction (via the call to `this->setDataPtr()`, and that it has a member function `void invert(std::size_t matrixSize);`

Comment: I see. I still consider it bad design if a class contains basically two pointers to the same array, but ok. Not something I'd expect in Effective C++...

Comment: Actually, the book states that the template parser wouldn't even consider base-class template members in name lookup until you add the "this->".  The use of this-> is similar to doing using BaseClass::FunctionName at the top of the scope where you would want to call the base class function from the derived class. So, it gets around the automatic hiding.

Answer (score 2):

It means the derived classes would contain inline functions, that would call the (heavy) non-inline functions in the base class doing actual work. The two variants compared are:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix {
...
  void invert();
...
};

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
void SquareMatrix::invert() {
   ... heavy code ...
}
```

and

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix : SquareMatrixBase<T> {
...
  void invert() { SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(pData.get(), n); }
...
};

template <typename T>
void SquareMatrixBase::invert(T* data, int n){
   ... heavy code ...
}
```

Now the second one emits the heavy code once per `T`, whereas the first one emits the heavy code once per `T` *and `n`*. That means more (pretty much identical) code in the second case.

Note that using inheritance for this trick is not mandatory, and I personally would use just free functions (maybe in a private namespace) instead.

Edit: the inlining is basically replacement of the function call by the function body (beta reduction, ha!). From

```
my_matrix.invert()
```

you get eg.

```
SquareMatrixBase<float>::invert(my_matrix.pData.get(), 3); <-- pseudocode
```

in the calling code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd appreciate an example though - your answer raises the same questions for me as the quote in the book.  I don't understand what code is being put where by the inlining in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the passage, it's a little hard to say exactly what's going on here, but if `SquareMatrix` is a templated "wrapper" class around a template base-class `SquareMatrixBase`, and the purpose of `SquareMatrix` is to basically pass the appropriate template parameters to the base-class, as well as provide a couple non-static data-members for the functions of the base-class to operate on, then you can, since the member-functions of `SquareMatrix` will basically be simple functions that are just calling the functions defined in the base-class, inline all the member functions for `SquareMatrix`.  The base-class `SquareMatrixBase` on the other-hand will have all the "heavy-lifting" functions that are not inlined, but are rather contained in another compiled code-module.

For instance, you mentioned that `SquareMatrixBase` had a function called:

```
void SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(std::size_t matrixSize);
```

In `SquareMatrix` you could simply call this function like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t n>
inline void SquareMatrix<T, std::size_t n>::invert() { SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(n); }
```

The inlined code version, even though it may be instantiated by many different types *and* sizes, will compile to a single function call ... the "heavy" base-class function will only need to be instantiated for each different *type*, not for every permutation of each various *size* of that type's matrix may need to be instantiated with ... so that will definitely cut down on the code bloat.  So `SquareMatrixBase<T>` will only need to be instantiated for types such as `int`, `double`, etc.  It contains all the "major" functions that use up a lot of code.  The `SquareMatrix<T, std::size_t n>` on the other-hand class can be instantiated for not only `int`, but for `int` and size {1, 2, 3, 4, ...}.  Each different template argument for the size of the matrix will instantiate a new version of `SquareMatrix<T, std::size_t n>`, but will only use a single instantiation for an `int` version of `SquareMatrixBase<T>`.

Comment: See my comment to MikeSeymour's answer.